# Struts: Setting Default Value for Radio Button without using List or ArrayList

Tags: java, struts2

So in my case, I have existing radio buttons created using Struts like so:

```
<s:radio property="myclass.radioValue" value="Value1" />
<s:radio property="myclass.radioValue" value="Value2" />
```

Where in myclass I get and set the radioValue like so:

```
private String rdValue;
public void setRadio(String rd) { this.rdValue = rd; }
public String getRadio() { return rdValue; }
```

I would like to set a default radio button if it's value on the database is null. After some research I read that I can use List or ArrayList to do this but I am using version 1.4 for the compiler and JRE so it doesn't work. This is for an existing project so I can't rebuild the project using later versions of the compiler. So my question is, would it be possible to set the default value without the use of lists or arraylists?

Comment: I don't understand. `List` and `ArrayList` existed in JDK 1.4. Also, you can compile code for earlier versions of Java by setting source/target levels. If nothing else, you're probably already using a retrotranslated version of S2 as it is.

Comment: Perhaps, I've misunderstood the error initially and explained incorrectly. I received the error: Eclipse: Syntax Error, parameterized types are only if source level is 1.5 or greater whenever I tried using List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>(). I'll add it to my original post.

Comment: Your `<s:radio>` looks a bit odd. Anyway you can set default value with expression in `value` attribute.

Comment: Don't use parameterized types then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this part of code

```
public String getRadio() { 
   if(rdValue == null || rdValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
       return "YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE";
   }

   return rdValue;
}
```

Comment: .trim().isEmpty() doesn't work. From what I understand, isEmpty hasn't been implemented in 1.4

Comment: @user1597438, you can write that on your own `rdValue.trim().length == 0` is nothing but `isEmpty`

Comment: Don't mess with the getters/setters, please.

Comment: @AleksandrM, I understand. I should set the default value in my init class, yes?

Comment: @user1597438: In class or in view if it is more convenient.